# backbone.js tag name has no effect after declared

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I think I've declared tagName correctly? and it's placed correctly under render method, but somehow the tag is div not h1.

https://jsfiddle.net/b01vtfnh/

```
        var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults:{
                name:"",
                age:20,
                job:'jobless'
            }
        });

        var person1 = new Person({
            name:"Sony",
            age: 30,
            job: "Teacher"
        });

        var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function(){
                this.render();
            },
            render: function(){
                tagName:'h1'; //this line won't work

                var li_person = this.model.get('name') + ', ' + this.model.get('age') + 
                ' (' + this.model.get('job') + ')';

                this.$el.html(li_person)
                return this;
            }
        });

        var person_view = new PersonView({model:person1});
        $('body').html(person_view.el)
```

Comment: as rockerest has answered, you have not placed *tagName* under the render method but inside it

Comment: Is one person posting under several accounts or did a group of students just start the same assignment? I've seen this "`tagName: 'li'` at the top of `render`" error several times over the past few days. Similarly for that `var li_person` (AKA `var html_content`) expression.

Comment: group assignment :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tagName` is a property of the view, not - somehow - of the render function. This should throw a syntax error as written. The correct structure would be:

```
initialize: function(){
    this.render();
},
tagName: 'h1',
render: function(){
...
```

---

I'm leaving the original so the comments make sense, but it turns out that `function(){ thing: "stuff"; }` is actually valid syntax. Regardless, in the context and the way it's used, it is incorrect for it to be positioned there.

Comment: "This should throw a syntax error as written." No, that's a [_label_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) statement.

Comment: Today I Learned about labels. How obscure! I'm on my phone or I suppose I would have seen that it didn't error.